# Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::limit()

Tags: mysql, query-builder

Call to undefined method `Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::limit()`

I have search the related Queries but not getting the results

```
public function getAllCTCCompensationData($ouCode,$langCode)
    { 
    $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder->select('ppp.payperiodSdesc, ppesa.grossPay, pptpp.pfEmployerContribution, pptpp.esiEmployerContribution, pplw.employercontribution')
        ->from(PyProcessEmpStatusApproved::class, 'ppesa')
        ->leftJoin(PyProcessTdsPfPt::class, 'pptpp', 'with', 'ppesa.ouCode = pptpp.ouCode')
        ->leftJoin(PyPayGroup::class, 'ppg', 'with', 'pptpp.pgCode = ppg.pgCode')
        ->leftJoin(PyProcessLabourWelfare::class, 'pplw', 'with', 'ppg.pgCode = pplw.pgCode')
        ->leftJoin(PyPayPeriod::class,'ppp','with','pplw.payperiodCode = ppp.payperiodCode')
        ->leftJoin(PyPayrollCalendar::class, 'ppc', 'with', 'ppp.paycalCode = ppc.paycalCode')
                ->where('ppesa.ouCode = ?1')
                ->andWhere('ppesa.langCode = ?2')
                ->setParameter('1','ouCode')
                ->setParameter('2','langCode')
                ->where('ppesa.ouCode','DESC')
                ->limit(20);

    $compData  = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $compData;
```

I want to apply limit condition in the query. How to apply limit to the Query?

for reference use this link https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#limit-and-offset-clauses

Why it is saying undefined method limit?

Comment: i using zendframework with doctrine Query builder  https://www.doctrine-project.org/

Comment: The reference link is from doctrine version 1, you are using version 2. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#limit-clause   Use ->setMaxResults(); which the equivelant to limit() of v1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `orderBy` before the `limit` , I thik this is the error.

```
public function getAllCTCCompensationData($ouCode,$langCode)
{ 
    $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder->select('ppp.payperiodSdesc, ppesa.grossPay, pptpp.pfEmployerContribution, pptpp.esiEmployerContribution, pplw.employercontribution')
        ->from(PyProcessEmpStatusApproved::class, 'ppesa')
        ->leftJoin(PyProcessTdsPfPt::class, 'pptpp', 'with', 'ppesa.ouCode = pptpp.ouCode')
        ->leftJoin(PyPayGroup::class, 'ppg', 'with', 'pptpp.pgCode = ppg.pgCode')
        ->leftJoin(PyProcessLabourWelfare::class, 'pplw', 'with', 'ppg.pgCode = pplw.pgCode')
        ->leftJoin(PyPayPeriod::class,'ppp','with','pplw.payperiodCode = ppp.payperiodCode')
        ->leftJoin(PyPayrollCalendar::class, 'ppc', 'with', 'ppp.paycalCode = ppc.paycalCode')
                ->where('ppesa.ouCode = ?1')
                ->andWhere('ppesa.langCode = ?2')
                ->setParameter('1','ouCode')
                ->setParameter('2','langCode')
                ->orderBy('ppesa.ouCode','DESC')
                ->limit(20);

    $compData  = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $compData;
}
```